# How to associate model for a controller which is different than one computed from Inflector class?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In `Cake 2.x`, models are lazy loaded in the controller if the name of controller and model follow a convention - pluralized controller, singularized model.

However, I have a scenario where my controller and model don't follow this convention. How do I load the model for each method of the controller?

One way is to use `loadModel` method of the controller. But I will have to repeat it in each method.

Answer (score 1):

> One way is to use loadModel method of controller. But I will have to repeat it in each method.

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks

Use beforeFilter().

However, this sounds like you're doing stuff in a controller that should be done in another controller that reflects what actually is inside the domain of the model you're using.